# Why I receive error 2042 in MATCH formula in my VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

```
If checkRECORD1 > 0 Then If checkRECORDvalue > 0 Then matchRECORD1 = 
Evaluate("INDEX(TEMPDB!E" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":E" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & _
",MATCH(STATIONS!B" & RARTSTAT3 &"& STATIONS!" & Cells(1, cARTIST).Address & _
" , TEMPDB!C" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":C" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & _
" & TEMPDB!A" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":A" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & "))")
```

Ok, I had some troubles with code above. To ease things up here is some clarification:
checkRECORD counts is there such entry in SEARCH table
checkRECORDvalue is checking does that entry have any value in specific column (can be text or number or empty)

What index/match should be return to is number in this case: 25 (in some other case can be text). Range is pretty much clear and criteria in this case is STATIONNAME and ARTISTNAME. Both exist when I check it manually (KJLU and HW-BREEZIN`) and also there is value to be returned - 25!

I read other articles about this issues, but didnt quite understood why and where would I need CLNG (solution from other thread)?

I constantly receive either 0 either error 2042 for matchRECORD1!

Comment: if you try debug.print then what is the output text for this line `STATIONS!B" & RARTSTAT3 &"& STATIONS!" & Cells(1, cARTIST).Address`

Comment: @Maddy - It returns STATION!B25 (depends on loop for RARTSTAT3) and STATION!A23 (depends on loop for cARTIST). I thought I got what the error is, but no, error is still here!

Comment: I searched and searched, still have no luck with this! Cells it should reffer to (criteria and return value) are both non-empty (criteria textual and return value numerical)